# Why hatov v'hametiv is only on wine

Tags: blessing, grapes-wine, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

Why is the blessing hatov v'hametiv recited only on wine?

and why is it said only in a case where a second type of wine is brought.

looking for the message behind the halacha

Comment: Isn't the bracha also said on hearing good news that also affect someone else? IIRC, SA mentions that if your father dies but leaves you a large inheritance you say both *Dayan Ha'emet* and *Hatov Vehamitiv*. So, I don't think this is limited to good wine, but, I'm glad you indirectly reminded me to buy a bottle of Alfasi Merlot :-)

Comment: @DanF He is referring to the bracha said on multiple versions of the same food.

Answer (score 3):

[This yeshiva.org.il article](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=10578) suggests an answer to your question:

> This is because wine is unique in that not only does it satiate, it also gladdens the heart. In addition, each type of wine has its own unique character, and when additional types of wine are consumed in company there is greater joy. This is why the sages instituted a special blessing over the consumption of additional types of wine (Berachot 59b; Tosefot and Rosh ad loc.).

Answer (score 1):

While the rabbinic understanding is sourced in Talmud Bavli Berachot 35b, it is based on the specific biblical (albeit, Ketuvim) application of 'to gladden/be happy' found in Psalms 104:15.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific - most of us here aren't all that familiar with random sources.

Comment: Harav Siddur birchas hanenenin 12.13 שמפני חשיבות היין שהוא משמח אלהים ואנשים תקנו חכמים עליו עוד ברכה כשמרבים בשמחה להביא ממנו לשתות עוד יין שני.   http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/piskey/52/12

Comment: And 12.19 there אבל לא השותה יחיד שכן משמעות הברכה הטוב לו והמטיב לחבירו שעמו. וגם שהחיינו אינו מברך כי לא תקנו הברכה אלא משום רבוי השמחה ובשותה יחידי אין רבוי שמחה כל כך ולכן גם אם חברו שותה היין זה בחדר אחר אינו מצטרף: